# Update SQL table php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I want to update my SQL table. My table name is `payment_all`. I didn't get any error but my database doesn't update. Here is my php code.

```
    <?php
$id="";
$opr="";
if(isset($_GET['opr']))
    $opr=$_GET['opr'];

if(isset($_GET['rs_id']))
    $id=$_GET['rs_id'];


//---Update Data---//
if(isset($_POST['btn_upd'])){
    $semester=$_POST['semtxt'];
    $s_name=$_POST['s_name'];
    $reg=$_POST['reg'];
    $fa_name=$_POST['factxt'];
    $pay_name=$_POST['papytxt'];
    $totalpay=$_POST['tptxt'];

    $sql_update=mysql_query("UPDATE payment_all SET
                            semester='$semester' ,
                            s_name='$s_name',
                            reg='$reg' ,
                            faculties_name='$fa_name' ,
                            payment_name='$pay_name' ,
                            tota_payl='$totalpay' 
                        WHERE payall_id=$id

                    ");

if($sql_update==true)
    $msg="Update success...";
else
    $msg="Update Fail!...";


}
?>
```

My table field are look like

> payall_id, stu_id, semester, s_name, reg, faculties_name,
>   payment_name, total_pay, date.

Please help.

Comment: what is your table name payment_update or payment_all.?

Comment: You never check for errors. That's why you do not get one. STOP using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Comment: You have typo in UPDATE query: `total_pay='$totalpay'`, not `tota_payl='$totalpay' `

Comment: sorry table name is "payment_all"

Comment: Add to your code: 
`if (!$sql_update) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid query: '.mysql_error());
}`

Comment: Thanks @VladimirKovpak I got the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this . You specified wrong column name `tota_payl`

```
$sql_update=mysql_query("UPDATE payment_all SET
                            semester='$semester' ,
                            s_name='$s_name',
                            reg='$reg' ,
                            faculties_name='$fa_name' ,
                            payment_name='$pay_name' ,
                            total_pay='$totalpay' 
                        WHERE payall_id=$id

                    ");
```

Comment: I got the error. It was the "total_pay" and "ss_id". It mistakenly wrote ss_id instead of "payall_id". Thanks for the help. :)